# Set Welcome Page using Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, spservices

Is it possible to set the Welcome Page of a SubSite using only Javascript? I'm looking to create an Onclick Event that does this. Anything would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to set the welcome page:

```
var context = null;

var web = null;

var rootFolder = null;

var welcomePage = 'SitePages/Home.aspx';

SetWelcomePage();

function SetWelcomePage()

{

  context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

  web = context.get_web();

  rootFolder = web.get_rootFolder();

  context.load(web);

  context.load(rootFolder);

  rootFolder.set_welcomePage(welcomePage);

  rootFolder.update();

  context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

}



function onSuccess()

{

  console.log('Welcome Page Set!');

}

function onFail()

{
  console.log('Error!');

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to create the function `SetWelcomePage`, instead of calling it? You also don't need to call `new` when calling `SP.ClientContext.get_current()`. You don't need to `load` the variables. Why not just do something like this: https://gist.github.com/eirikb/eec211d3abc19cfe142c1c5753c19303 (untested)?

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Ahmed Mahmoud is not wrong (and should perhaps be marked accepted), calling [set_welcomePage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245093.aspx) on SPWeb RootFolder is the correct approach.
But the provided examples doesn't run, so I have decided to provide a couple of alternative code examples.
Note, they use features from **ES6**, and the variable `subWeb` refer to server-relative or absolute URL as of OP's question.

### JSOM

```
const context = new SP.ClientContext(subWeb);
const rootFolder = context.get_web().get_rootFolder();
rootFolder.set_welcomePage('SitePages/NewHome.aspx');
rootFolder.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(
  () => console.log('Done'), 
  (a, b) => console.error(b.get_message()));
```

### REST

```
const digest = document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value;
fetch(`${subWeb}/_api/Web/RootFolder`, {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({WelcomePage: 'SitePages/NewHome.aspx'}),
  headers: {
    'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-RequestDigest': digest
  }
});
```